# Geolocation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, geolocation

The following code returns in the console:

Cannot call method 'setCenter' of undefined

```
this.locateUser = function() {
    if(navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var latitude = position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                var coords = google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                self.map.setCenter(coords);
            });
    }
```

It looks like there is sth wrong with the coords

Answer (score 1):

Your code block is incomplete, so I have to guess a lot here: You're accessing `self.map.setCenter`. The error message says "Cannot call method 'setCenter' of undefined", so while `self` is defined, `self.map` isn't. Your code doesn't include a definition of `self` or `self.map`, so the issue is likely elsewhere.

Additionally, you shouldn't declare and use `self` as a variable in your code, since `self` is never undefined (it refers to `window` if not declared locally). Use `var that = this;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 map.setCenter(new GLatLng(latitude, -longitude), 13);
```